# How can I download all the videos I uploaded on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I uploaded many videos on my YouTube account: how can I retrieve them easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/) provides [Google Takeout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Takeout), which allows Google users to export their data to a downloadable ZIP file. Here is the link to export one's Youtube videos: https://www.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/youtube . It will create and Containing all the original uploaded videos.

[image]

Comment: Currently, at least for me and several others, this won't include videos. To get videos too you'll need to arrive at Takeout from YouTube, as described here: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/20414256?hl=en

Comment: @Piedone thanks good to know, maybe that changed since I wrote the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to download your own videos uploaded to YouTube at 720p or 360p resolution (depending on the size of the movie) and download the video as an MP4 video file. You can also use Google Take Out to download any videos you upload.

Here are the specific steps.

1. Log in to YouTube on your computer.
2. Select the "Account" icon in sequence and then [YouTube Studio (Beta)].
3. Select the [Movies] tab in the left panel.
4. Move the cursor to the movie you want to download, then select [Menu] > [Download].